# Prevent users from disabling or uninstalling a Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm building a Firefox add-on for children where I need to prevent them from disabling/uninstalling it.

[image: add-ons dialog]

I don't want them to be able to either remove or disable the add-on once it's installed.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think this is more of a programming issue.

Comment: If a kid is technically inclined enough to disable a Firefox add-on, then the battle is already lost.

Comment: Please, don't do this outside a corporate environment. Is really, REALLY annoying.

Comment: Hey, I need to do this too!  As a parent myself, I think if a parent wants to install an add-on and not let their kid uninstall it, nothing wrong with that.  Parent's should have as many rights as an employer, so if OK for corp., ok for parents :)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the access to add-on manager after you install the extension and then hide the shortcut in the bar. this works for me
Create a txt (windows) with this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox]
"DisablePrivateBrowsing"=dword:00000000
"DisableFirefoxAccounts"=dword:00000000
"BlockAboutAddons"=dword:00000001
```

then change the .txt into .reg and execute

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

> Windows Registry extension
>   Installing or updating certain software on Windows can register an extension for Firefox or Thunderbird. For example, a Windows Registry entry to install a Firefox extension can be added under one of these keys:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions\
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions\
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions (Only on 64-bit versions of Windows)
>   The Registry entry name will be the ID name or GUID of the add-on and the value data will be the path to the folder containing the extension (see Adding Extensions using the Windows Registry - MDC for details). When Firefox or Thunderbird next starts, it will notice the entry and install the extension.

[source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3A_FAQs_%3A_Uninstall_Extensions#Global_extension)

Answer (score 0):

You need a supplemental program to do the work.

[This mozillazine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_Uninstall_Extensions#Global_extension) has information:

> In a few cases, an extension may be installed globally into the Mozilla installation directory. Installing a global extension is something an administrator might do so that the add-on can be used by any user on the machine. It is also possible that another software installation may have included a global extension (for example, the Java JRE installer adds a global extension to Firefox, for the Java Console). To manually uninstall a global extension, open the "extensions" directory in your Mozilla application's installation directory and remove the directory that corresponds to the extension you want to uninstall.

And [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_Uninstall_Extensions#Windows_Registry_extension):

> Extensions that are installed this way include the Java Quick Starter extension for Firefox (see above), the Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant the RealPlayer Browser Record Plugin extension, and the Lenovo ThinkVantage Password Manager extension for Firefox. Although you can disable the extension in the Add-ons manager, the Uninstall option may not be functional (it will be "greyed out). In such cases, experienced users can uninstall the extension by removing the associated Registry entry and/or the contents of the folder containing the extension; otherwise, simply disable it.